# Hiding URL fAddress bar in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

Hi i want to hide url from address. i'm trying to download excel file but it's generating a new link and redirecting to new tab. when i copy and paste the same URL its downloading the same data. to restrict that tried authentication and all. now i am trying to hide that URL
i have tried with below code

```
var winFeature = 'location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'
window.open(result as string,winFeature);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the URL bar is part of window element of browser. You cannot change window's properties without affecting the whole tab's behaviour due to security issues. You can hide the URL bar only if fullscreen. For that I recommend the [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)
Also read this thread from [Google Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3627396?hl=en)